# Firebase snapshot to map in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dictionary, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make a route about information of summer camps. I want to use firebase and I almost done the data part but I can't "convert" it to map. taborId is a TextEditingController. My conception is to add a camp by it's id. I would use the document id to identify the camp. I have a textfield and I try to get the document. If it's successful, I want to save the data to shared preferences (json.encode). Therefore, I wanted to extract the map from the snapshot. I tried this methot but it was unsuccessful. I don't know how to convert a Stream of Map to a real Map or something like this.

```dart
try {
                                  final tmp=db
                                .collection("campdata")
                                    .doc(taborId.text).snapshots().map((event) => event.data());
                                  showToast(data["name"]);
                                } catch (e) {
                                  showToast(e.toString());
                                  print(e.toString());
                                }
```

Can anyone help me? I searched about the internet but I haven't find anything. I don't want to use streambuilder because I only want to use one document, not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to read a document from Firestore.

With Stream you add a listener to a Firestore document and if any changes occurs, the build method will be triggered with the new data.

1. Setup a Stream

   ```
   Stream readSomething(String docId){
       return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("campdata").doc(docId).snapshots();
   }
   ```
2. Use it in a StreamBuilder

   ```
   StreamBuilder(
       stream: DatabaseClass().readSomething(taborId),
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
           if (snapshot.hasData){
               return showToast(snapshot.data["name"]);
           } else {
               return Container();
           }
       }
   );
   ```

Using a Future

With Future, you wait for a single read to the document.

1. Setup a Future

   ```
   Future<Map> getSomething(String docId) async {
       CollectionRefference campRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("campdata");
       return await campRef.doc(docId).get().then((value) => value.data());
   }
   ```
2. Using it in a FutureBuilder

   ```
   FutureBuilder(
       stream: DatabaseClass().getSomething(taborId),
       builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Map> snapshot) {
           if (snapshot.hasData){
               return showToast(snapshot.data["name"]);
           } else {
               return Container();
           }
        }
       );
   ```